# Selenium send keys (text), selecting from dropdown and hit enter

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, sendkeys

I'm trying to trawl this website: http://www.jackson-stops.co.uk/

The data is not showing in the URL so I'm using a chromedriver.

My code is:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    //setup chromedriver
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    try {
        driver.get("http://www.jackson-stops.co.uk/");
        //begin the simulation
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sliderLocation\"]"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", menu);
        menu.sendKeys("Knightsbridge");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        Select menu2 = new Select(menu);
        menu2.selectByVisibleText("Knightsbridge");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + exp);
        //close and quit windows
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
    //close and quit windows
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
   exception:org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

How would I be able to select a location and hit enter because I tried inspecting the HTML and the options are dynamically loaded so not visible!

Comment: Once you open the url what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to go to the property page so for example sendKeys puts in "knightsbridge" but I cant return or click enter because a dropdownlist is needed.  Therefore I need to select from a dynamic load, then click submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to select an element but it's not select list, it's a link, So all you have to do is to click that element, that's all

First of all pass value

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sliderLocation']")).sendKeys("Knightsbridge")
```

Once it's done, it populate the values, So You need to click one of option, So you can directly click the element like this(since this population is taking time, you need to use implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

And then write

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Knightsbridge, London']")).click()
```

Or if you want to choose the element which consist of `Knightsbridge` then write the following code and this will choose the first option which consist of `Knightsbridge` then write

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Knightsbridge']")).click()
```

You don't have to use sleep statement anywhere in your selenium code, selenium automatically waits after the click until everything settle down properly. The one exceptional case is, If your page got refreshed after placing the value in your text box(Not necessary for select_list), then you need to use the implicit wait, otherwise even implicit wait is not necessary.

The above code I converted from Ruby to Java, the original code which I used to check is from selenium Ruby binding, the code is below

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='sliderLocation']").send_keys "Knightsbridge"
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Knightsbridge')]").click
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[text()='Knightsbridge, London']").click
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below:

```html
 String requiredCity = "London";
         List<WebElement> menu2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-3']/li"));
         System.out.println("Total options: "+menu2.size());
         
         for(int i=0;i<menu2.size();i++)
         {
          String CurrentOption = menu2.get(i).getText();
          
          if(CurrentOption.contains(requiredCity)){
           System.out.println("Found the city : "+CurrentOption);
           menu2.get(i).click();
          }
         }
```

Comment: I'm running the code, so far so good.  How did you find the xpath of the dynamic dropdownlist??   Great work

Comment: Good question Kevster... I actually had used Inspect in Chrome and missed the point that it is dynamic :(
We can use this instead: 
 List<WebElement> menu2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]/li/a"));

Answer (score 0):

This is the full solution using Ranjeet's answer.

```
           File file = new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    try {
        driver.get("http://www.jackson-stops.co.uk/");
        //begin the simulation
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sliderLocation\"]"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", menu);
        menu.sendKeys("London");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        String requiredCity = "London";
        List<WebElement> menu2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-3']/li"));
        System.out.println("Total options: " + menu2.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < menu2.size(); i++) {
            String CurrentOption = menu2.get(i).getText();

            if (CurrentOption.contains(requiredCity)) {
                System.out.println("Found the city : " + CurrentOption);
                menu2.get(i).click();
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                menu.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(8000);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + exp);
        //close and quit windows
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
    //close and quit 
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to grab all the options first before you click it and I don't understand why you need to iterate all the options and click the required one, while you can simply use this line to click it `@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Knightsbridge')]").click` this checks whether the options contains the value of `Knightsbridge` and click it.

Comment: Because...  There is only 5 options and is useful for future developments.

Saying this, I would rate your answer but I have not got enough points.  Whenever I explain too well, there is always someone who doesn't help. LOL

Comment: So what? you have 5 options or 10 options, however you are going to enter the value into the text_field and and going to choose the element in which your required text present, right? For that, you don't have to save the options and and iterating to choose one of among them, you simply write xpath using consist() and it will do it's Job.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//div/select/option[@value='Your value']")));
    selectMyElement.sendKeys("Your value");
    Actions keyDown = new Actions(myLauncher.getDriver());
    keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.